# Can I add route for controller with parameters?

Tags: asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-routing

Can I use route attribute for controller and the attribute has parameters, not only constant string in ASP.NET Core?
ex. I want add undermentioned definition controller

```
 [Route("api/sth/{Id}/sth2/latest/sth3")]
 public class MyController : Controller
 {
    public object Get() 
    {
      return new object();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sure you can, but that tends to be tricky if you don't  plan well.

Let's assume that your owin `Startup` class is set to default WebApi routes with `app.UseMvc()`

This code below works fine and returns `["value1", "value2"]` independent of the value `{id}`

`curl http://localhost:5000/api/values/135/foo/bar/`

```
[Route("api/values/{id}/foo/bar")]
public partial class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

this works fine as well, returning the specified value in route parameter in this case `135`

`curl http://localhost:5000/api/values/135/foo/bar/`

```
[Route("api/values/{id}/foo/bar")]
public partial class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public int GetById(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**But** if you combine those 2 actions in the same controller, it'll return a 500 as there are 2 methods that can respond your request.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RoutePrefix` in a fashion similar to this, and then add `Route`s to each method as required. Parameters defined in the route prefix are still passed to the method in the same way as specifying them in a route on the method.

For example, you could do this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/sth/{id}/sth2/latest/sth3")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    /// <example>http://www.example.com/api/sth/12345/sth2/latest/sth3</example>
    [Route()]  // default route, int id is populated by the {id} argument
    public object Get(int id)
    {
    }

    /// <example>http://www.example.com/api/sth/12345/sth2/latest/sth3/summary</example>
    [HttpGet()]
    [Route("summary")]
    public object GetSummary(int id)
    {
    }

    /// <example>http://www.example.com/api/sth/12345/sth2/latest/sth3/98765</example>
    [HttpGet()]
    [Route("{linkWith}")]
    public object LinkWith(int id, int linkWith)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: In the ASP.NET Core we can use RoutePrefix too?

Comment: I've not used .NET Core, so I couldn't say, sorry. If you are using .NET Core I would add that to your question.